# Error [42000][1064] for generated virtual column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I try to update generated column with expression. It works in select

```
select from_unixtime(CONCAT(LEFT(jdoc->'$.ts', LENGTH(jdoc->'$.ts') - CHAR_LENGTH(jdoc->'$.sts')), jdoc->'$.sts'))  as calc_ts
from table_name
```

but it doesn work when i alter the table

```
alter table table_name
    alter column sts_date set default from_unixtime(
                CONCAT(LEFT(jdoc -> '$.ts', LENGTH(jdoc -> '$.ts') - CHAR_LENGTH(jdoc -> '$.sts')), jdoc -> '$.sts') /
                1000);
```

it returns me error:

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from_unixtime( CONCAT(LEFT(jdoc -> '$.ts', LENGTH(jdoc -> '$.ts'' at line 2.
```

what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, MySQL 5.7 doesn't support expressions for the DEFAULT clause. That feature is new as of MySQL 8.0.13. Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html If you are still using MySQL 5.7, you will have to upgrade to get this feature.

Second, expression defaults require an extra pair of parentheses.

Wrong:

```
DEFAULT expr
```

Right:

```
DEFAULT (expr)
```

Notice the [syntax reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) shows the parentheses:

```
column_definition: {
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT {literal | (expr)} ]
                                                    ^    ^
```

Comment: it didn't help. but i could create a new column

Comment: I actually tested your code before I wrote my answer, and it does work.

Comment: mysql 5.7 [HY000][1221] Incorrect usage of DEFAULT and generated column.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: thanks, i just created a new column and it worked